# async task in python gtk3

Tags: python, gtk3

My app has a `Gtk.Grid` and her children are loaded dynamically

```
for item in self.read_items_from_file():
    # ...
    self.my_grid.attach(self.build_widget(item), col, row, 1, 1)
```

for each item is built a widget and for widget a image is generated.

this process takes time and I wanna convert the previous code in an asynctask.

**How can achieve this?**

I'm using python3 and GTK+3.0 and Ubuntu

---

### Update using futures

I'm trying to use futures but nothing happens the windows is shown but the items are not attached to the grid, this is the code

```
def attach(item):
    # ...
    self.my_grid.attach(self.build_widget(item), col, row, 1, 1)  

with futures.ProcessPollExecutor() as executor:
    executor.map(attach, self.read_items_from_file())
```

Comment: Use `concurrent.futures` to run your heavy task and sync with the main thread to update the GUI.

Comment: @razpeitia can you provide and example